# Extending Xfinity WiFi

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-extender

I have an Xfinity cable wifi account but the nearest hotspot is out of range (just outside the building where I work. I do not have physical access to the Xfinity equipment.)

I'd like to access the internet on my tablet... **Will a wifi extender work?**

Another source says NO, since an extender cannot authenticate with a user name and password. Is there a means to accomplish this with an XP netbook, converting it into an extender?

Answer (score 0):

If the netbook can receive/transmit from the distances you need, you can use an XP netbook by using it as a bridge.  It is unlikely that you have an internal chip capable of running as an access point, so you'll need to either install one (USB would work fine) or configure a wireless router with a crossover cable plugged into the netbooks ethernet port to complete your bridge.

In case you have some hardware available now, here are some instructions on creating a bridge which can be used with a wireless router:  https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_sharing

Then you can connect your tablet to the router like normal.